# is it possible to print PDF template from file in flutter mobile

Tags: flutter, mobile, pdf-generation

I'm trying to find a way i can print a pdf in flutter from a file template the way you can in RDLC or crystal reports. i want to throw the file an object and the file is a template to be independent from the app where i can just swap files to swap templates or customize them to my desire. The alternative to this in Microsoft Visual Studio is a file type `.rdlc` where you just remove the file and swap it with another file and the template changes. If there is no solution for this I'm open to hearing alternative ways of achieving this

i tried researching a lot but nothing is found on this topic. all that pops up is flutter web or react native i have no clue on how to approach this matter.